# Help with JSON to format column to show picture instead of URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, image, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a contact list created in SharePoint Online.

My list has a column called "Picture URL".

The "Picture URL" column is formatted as "Single line of Text".

I have formatted the "Picture URL" column with:

```
{
   "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "children": [
     {
       "elmType": "img",
       "attributes": {
         "src": "@currentField",
         "title": "=if(@currentField == '', 'No picture available', @currentField)"
       },
       "style": {
         "position": "relative",
         "top": "50%",
         "left": "50%",
         "width": "48px",
         "height": "auto",
         "margin-left": "-50%",
         "margin-top": "0%"
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

This in the hope that the URL will show as a thumbnail picture.

But all I see is a black square with a White Cross.

Comment: Try inspecting the image element generated using this json and check its `src` attribute. It is correct or not?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this JSON. probably the image URL is wrong

Comment: Checked the image url..... opened the jpg and copied with url...... everything is correct on the URL

Comment: Not sure how to check the src attribute

Comment: Where is the image stored? In a SharePoint library? Elsewhere on the web? Like Denis said, your JSON works. I just tested it. So it must be a URL issue or permissions issue. To check the rendered URL: Press F12 to open the browser's developer tools, click the tab named Inspector or DOM Explorer, click the "select element" tool (usually an arrow), then click your image black square. In the tool pane you will then see the generated HTML. Note the "src" attribute in the img tag and see if is correct. (Copy it and test in a browser.)

Comment: Image is saved in a SharePoint site folder.  What I did was to open the image.  Then once opened copied the URL from the address bar.  Then paste this into the list field.

Answer (score 0):

Your json format is fine, you need set the field value point to a image.

For example:

Set Picture URL as image relative url.

```
/sites/lee/siteassets/panda.jpg
```

or

```
https://d2ouvy59p0dg6k.cloudfront.net/img/web_105346_358521.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I can get your Panda to disply but not my image.

Comment: Here is the full link to the jpg, which maybe needs to be corrected with backslashes etc

Comment: /sites/SRO-992/pac/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSRO%2D100%2Fpac%2FSiteAssets%2FSitePages%2FStaff%20Photos%2Fdarren%2Ejpg

Comment: The link is not an image url actually, it'll render if you view from browser is because of SharePoint has logic to process it, an image url should point to a image directly.

Comment: Is this better:

Comment: https://xxxxxuk.sharepoint.com/sites/SRO-023/pac/XXX%20Estates%20Staff%20Photos/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FSRO%2D023%2Fpac%2FXXX%20Estates%20Staff%20Photos%2FDarren%20Spark%2Ejpg&parent=%2Fsites%2FSRO%2D023%2Fpac%2FXXX%20Estates%20Staff%20Photos